# Fast DSP with in-chip ADCs

Tags: sampling, dsp-core

I'm looking for a DSP, around 500MHz, with an in-chip ADC (preferably 2 but 1 will suffice) that samples around 20MSPS. Does any such DSP exist or do I have to use external ADCs?

Comment: Those are pretty ambitious goals. You won't find many DSPs that run that fast that have integrated ADCs. In addition, I've never seen a CPU that had an ADC that can run as fast as 20 MSPS.  Typically, DSP processors will contain a number of high-speed bus interfaces for interfacing hardware like ADCs. You might find that in order to support that high of a sample rate, you might need a more hardware-based approach using something more like an FPGA.